How to fix missing vite manifest.json file in laravel project?
I created a laravel project and i run to the following issue after upgrading node package:
Vite manifest not found at: /Users/Documents/AppTest/public/build/manifest.json
But I find out the manifest.json file is place in a different location public/build/.vite/manifest.json instead of public/build/manifest.json. Here is my vite.config.js file content:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'node_modules': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
      '@/fonts': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/fonts'),
      '@/images': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/images'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: ['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
      refresh: [
        {
          paths: ['resources'],
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1000,
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          let extType = assetInfo.name.split('.').pop();

          if (/png|jpe?g|svg|gif|webp|tiff|bmp|ico/i.test(extType)) {
            extType = 'images';
          } 
          else if (/woff|woff2/.test(extType)) {
            extType = 'css';
          }

          return `${extType}/[name]-[hash][extname]`;
        },
        chunkFileNames: 'js/[name]-[hash].js',
        entryFileNames: 'js/[name]-[hash].js',
      },
    },
  },
});

I recreated the a new project and upgrade node package. When i run yarn dev there is no issue but whenever i build for production i get the issue.
